# scramble word where if the letter "a" is present it switches to the previous postion

Tags: java, string, swap

So i have to write a program and so far i've had some luck in getting the program to do what i want. Firs to of all, i am supposed to make a java program that takes a word like "tan" and swaps the a and n to give you "tna." Although, if i put the word aardvark into the program so far, it swaps all the a's correctly but it cuts off k in the final output. If someone could help, that would be much appreciated.

```
    String word = "aardvark";
    String combined = "";
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < word.length() && j < word.length(); i++, j++) {

        if (word.substring(i, j).equals("a")) {
            combined = combined + word.substring(i + 1, j + 1)+ word.substring(i, j);
            i++;
            j++;

        }

        else {
            combined = combined + word.substring(i, j);
        }

    }
    System.out.print(combined);
```

Comment: what is the desired output of "aadvark" ?

Comment: it should have been "aardvarak" as the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want, keep it simple:

```
        String word = "aardvark";
        char[] symbols = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length - 1; ++i) {
            if (symbols[i] == 'a') { // have to swap with the next symbol
               symbols[i] = symbols[i + 1];
               symbols[i + 1] = 'a';
               ++i;
            }
        }

        String scrambled = new String(symbols);
        System.out.println("scrambled  = " + scrambled); // aardvrak
```